# Rename tag [embedded]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just stumbled upon [embedded](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded) during review but for the sake of consistency can we rename it to [embed](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embed) or [embedding](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedding)?

Most verb tags are either on the infinitive form ( [export](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export)  [print](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print) [resize](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resize) ) when it's about an action or active participle ([typesetting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting) [illustrator-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illustrator-scripting) [image-editing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editing)) when it's about a process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We renamed [embedded](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded) to [embed](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embed), and made both [embedded](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded) and [embedding](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedding) synonyms. Thanks for catching that! Changes may still be caching.

Comment: No problem! I also still see [embedding] so I'm not sure what's the newly created synonym.